# How to style div such that it occupies all the remaining space of the parent left by its siblings?

Tags: html, css

I have two div (children inside a div) say `div1` and `div2`. `div1` has a fixed width, but `div2` occupies all the remaining space (width).

If the div (parent div) has width of 100% i.e. not fixed width, then how should I style `div2` such that it takes all the remaining space of div and they appear side by side?

**EDIT::**

```
    body{ padding: 0; margin: 0; font:0.9em arial,verdana,tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;}

    #wrap{ widht: 100%;}

    #header{ width: 100%; background: black; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 20px;}

    #navigation{ width: 170px; height: 500px; float: left; margin-left: 20px;padding: 0 20px; border-right: solid 1px #CCCCCC;}

    #bodywrap{width: 100%; float: left;}

    #body{ min-height: 500px; margin-left: 20px; }

    #footer{ width: 100%; height: 60px; background: black; float: left; margin-top: 20px; }
```

by html code is

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <!-- end of header -->

    <div id="bodywrap">
        <div id="navigation">
        </div>
        <div id="body">             
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end for body -->

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    <!-- end of footer -->      
</div>
```

and I want body to take all remaining space left by navigation.

Comment: your edit gives a stretched body-div as intended in Chrome, what browserversion (of IE :p) are you using?

Comment: @Sam firefox 3.6 and i am getting body all over the body wrap

Comment: Your code looks like it does what you asked for in IE7/8, Chrome. What's wrong with your code?

Comment: @thirtydot in chrome it same as firefox(body is stretched over navigation). my code is all messed up with php this is what i copied from browser source and my css source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here: try adding `padding-left: 230px` to `#body`.

Comment: Try `padding` first, if that doesn't work, try `margin` instead :D. Otherwise, I don't think I understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this

HTML

```
<div class="prnt">
    <div class="fl div1">
        --div1 --
    </div>
    <div class="fl div2">
       -- div2 --
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.prnt{
    padding-left:100px;
}

.fl{
    float:left;
    height:100px
}

.div1{
    width:100px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    background:#f00
}

.div2{
    width:100%;
    background:#0f0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, if I understood you correctly, that this should be it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test div</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #left {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    #right {
        background-color: #cccccc;
        margin: 0 0 0 200px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">fixed left</div>
        <div id="right">stretched right</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

added margin to assist Chris' issues with the first draft..

Comment: You should indent the last line.

Comment: @Sam you are right but still i am not being able to implement on my site could you help me out

Comment: I can't do much more then what I have shown in my post mate, not sure what else needs to be done, maybe you could give more information or a url to what is supposed to be working but is not

Comment: @Sam it's okay i am running on my local server, i know the width of my screen but i want the same to happen with all other user's screen.

Comment: This doesn't do what is desired (by my interpretation) if there is too much text in the right box. see http://jsfiddle.net/P2k4j/ for an example. The text on the right wraps to underneath the left currently.

Comment: @Chris i think i will be very useful in for adding text and images

Comment: @Sam: I figured you could fix it easily enough which is why I left the comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

my solution is the following:

**css**

```
#container {width:100%; height:200px;}
#first {width:100px; height:100%; background:black; float:left;}
#second {height:100%;width:auto; background:blue; margin-left:100px;}
```

**html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first"></div><div id="second"></div>
  </div>
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/erure4

The `first` div has a fixed width of 100px and is floated left. This make the `second` div to stick near it. The `second` div will normally get all the width override the `first` div, for this reason it needs to give a `margin-left:100px;` (the width of the `first` div).